# Test if a given number is a Vampire Number

Tags: code-golf, math

*EDIT:* In the interest of increasing the complexity, i've added more to the challenge.

> In mathematics, a vampire number (or
>   true vampire number) is a composite
>   natural number v, with an even number
>   of digits n, that can be factored into
>   two integers x and y each with n/2
>   digits and not both with trailing
>   zeroes, where v contains precisely all
>   the digits from x and from y, in any
>   order, counting multiplicity. x and y
>   are called the fangs.

More about [Vampire Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_number)

Pseudovampire numbers

> Pseudovampire numbers are similar to
>   vampire numbers, except that the fangs
>   of an n-digit pseudovampire number
>   need not be of length n/2 digits.
>   Pseudovampire numbers can have an odd
>   number of digits, for example 126 =
>   6×21.

#### Input

Accept Numbers from command line or stdin

#### Output

- "1260 = 21 * 60" *(smaller fang first if the number is a Vampire.)*
- "1261 is not a Vampire Number." *(if the number is not a Vampire number)*
- "126 = 6 * 21". *(if the number is a Pseudovampire number)*

EDIT: If the number has multiple fangs, display it so.

```
x = fang1a * fang1b = fang2a * fang2b
```

Comment: I've decided not to include Prime vampire's, i won't go overboard with it.

Comment: Maybe i should add Printing if its a Vampire or a PseudoVampire, what do you guys say?

Comment: What about multiple pairs of fangs?

Comment: @gnibbler, i'll ammend it.

Comment: If number has several pair, does their order important? I mean `125460 = 204 * 615 = 246 * 510` or `125460 = 246 * 510 = 204 * 615`? Or doesn't matter?

Comment: BTW, there is still no *increasing the complexity*, because nothing denied to use full permutations' processing, as we solved with gnibbler. Another thing is that it could be not golf problem, but smth like *how large number can you find, which has exactly n pairs*, but it's already another question, and this can't be modified so.

Comment: @Nakilon, print them in the increasing order. `fang1a` appears before `fang2a` when `fang1a < fang2a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Python - 188 chars

Doesn't do Pseudovampire numbers

```py
from itertools import*
n=input()
a=[]
for i in map("".join,permutations(`n`)):x,y=int(i[::2]),int(i[::-2]);a+=[(x,y)]*(x*y==n)
print n,a and"=%s*%s"%min(a)or"is not a Vampire Number"
```

Comment: Also doesn't handle multiple pairs (for 125460) and space missed after `=`.

Comment: (checked [here](http://ideone.com/qnTEf))

Comment: @Nakilon, this answer predates the amendment for multiple pairs

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 190 chars

```rb
o=[]
[*x.chars].permutation{|r|a=r.pop(x.size/2).join.to_i
r=r.join.to_i
o|=[[a,r]]if a<=r&&a*r==x.to_i}
puts x+(o.any? ? o.map{|i|" = "+i*" * "}*"":" is not a Vampire Number.")
```